# MacOS High Sierra: how can I merge 2 partitions into one?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, ssd, high-sierra

Well, I've got a little problem with my SSD.

I had Windows installed through the bootcamp, when macOS offered me a High Sierra update. I've updated. But when I wanted to remove Windows, I could not do it. I had to delete it via the Disk Utility. And then I ran into a problem: I had 2 containers on one internal physical disk.

[image: Divided ssd]

But how do I unite them now, so that the empty merged with the system without loss of information?

Here is my diskutil list:

[image]

Comment: @klanomath thank you for quick response It seems I cannot get any output:

gpt show: unable to open device 'disk0': Operation not permitted

Comment: Your forgot to prepend `sudo `

Comment: So guys, what should I do now? How I can disable System Integrity Protection?

Comment: @klanomath sorry, my mistake! Yes, I have High Sierra

Comment: You may post the output of `diskutil list`.

Comment: @klanomath, I upload screenshot of diskutil list info
Thanks again for your help

Comment: So guys? Any solution of my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the commands given below to preform the merge.

> Note: These commands will delete the `noname` volume, therefore you may want to backup this volume.

```
diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk0s3
diskutil eraseVolume free n disk0s3
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

If a command fails, try prepending a `sudo`.

Comment: Also worked well for me. I merged two partitions on an external hard drive via `diskutil mergePartitions ExFAT DesiredVolumeName disk2s1 disk2s2`

Comment: It worked for me on 10.13.5.

Answer (score 0):

**Below answer is given by Apple Tech Support guy.**

Open terminal -> type distutil list -> type diskutil mergePartitions JHFS+ Macintosh disk0s2 disk0s4

**Note:**
disk0s2 is the SSD
disk0s4 is the disk which you want to erase and merge into main disk SSD.

Hope this helps!