# How to combine two partitons on an external hard drive

Tags: mac, partition

How do I combine two partitions on my external hard drive into one?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This answer may help. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310655/macos-high-sierra-how-can-i-merge-2-partitions-into-one

Comment: @Harry McGovern's link probably is to a valid answer. If not, update your questioning and include the entire output from the command `diskutil list disk2`.

Comment: After deleting the containers I was able to create a single partition.